# Only Integers Transferred when Joining by Location

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, fields-attributes, spatial-join

When joining attributes from a points layer to a polygon layer of Postcodes, only the integer fields from the points layer are transferred. See screenshots below.

Points Layer
[image: Points Layer]
Points Layer Continued
[image: Points Layer Continued]

Postcode Layer
[image: Postcode Layer]

Setting up the algorithm...
[image]

Comment: did you try other summary statistics that would work for non numeric fields